# How to associate the 'MarkerSize' to a value that means the radius of a plotted circle?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter

I have three vectors of the same length. Two of them contain the `X` and `Y` coordinates of what I want to plot. The third one contains values that I want to associate the radius of the plotted circle.

I have read that `'MarkerSize'` in `plot` corresponds the number of points in the circumference, and if I want to use `scatter`, the third vector corresponds to the area of the plotted circle.

Nonetheless, I want my third vector to be associated with the radius

As such, how to associate the size of the circles with the radius?

I have this using `plot`:

```
hold on;
for nd = 1 : 24
    plot(xL(nd), -yL(nd), 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerSize', attribute(nd))
end
```

And this using `scatter`:

```
hold on;
for nd = 1 : 24    
    scatter(xL(nd), -yL(nd), attribute(nd), 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k')
end
```

Thanks in advance for this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `MarkerSize` as the attribute for `plot`, as you said, this number reports the circumference of the plotted marker in pixels.

Well, you know there's a relationship between the circumference of a circle and its radius:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Math Is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/)</sup>

Therefore, the circumference of a circle is equal to `pi` multiplied by the diameter, which is twice the radius... so:

```
C = 2*pi*r
```

`C` would be the `MarkerSize` attribute.  So, given a radius, simply multiply by `2*pi` to get the desired circumference.  Bear in mind that the above computation will yield floating point values, so either take the `floor`, take the `ceil` or `round` to get the desired effect.

In other words, do this to your `attribute` vector, assuming you are reporting the **radius**:

```
attribute = floor(2*pi*attribute);
```

Now use this with `MarkerSize` and `plot`.

---

On the other hand, if you want to use `scatter`... well you know there's a relationship between the area of a circle and its radius:

[image]
<sub>(source: [whstatic.com](http://pad3.whstatic.com/images/thumb/2/2f/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Circle-Step-7-Version-2.jpg/670px-Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Circle-Step-7-Version-2.jpg))</sub>

<sup>Source: [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Circle)</sup>

Therefore, given the radius, simply square the radius and multiply by `pi` to get the area, then use this as the third parameter to `scatter`... again, accounting for floating-point precision:

```
attribute = floor(pi*attribute.^2);
```

You can now use this with `scatter`.

Comment: Is there any better answer? I doubt that. @rayryeng. Thank so much for your answer and the amount of detail that makes your answer better.

Comment: @Gohann - You're welcome :) please consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help. Good luck!